# jackson: deserialize a custom exception

Tags: java, exception, jackson

I am trying to get Jackson to deserialize a JSON-encoded custom exception, and it fails if the exception disables the stacktrace.

Working example:

```
public static class CustomException extends Exception {
    public CustomException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }
}

@Test
public void testSerializeAndDeserializeCustomException() throws Exception {
    log.info("Test: testSerializeAndDeserializeCustomException");

    CustomException ex1 = new CustomException("boom");
    ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();

    String json = om.writerFor(CustomException.class).writeValueAsString(ex1);
    assertNotNull(json);
    log.info("JSON: {}", json);

    CustomException ex2 = om.readerFor(CustomException.class).readValue(json);
    assertNotNull(ex2);
    assertEquals(ex2.getMessage(), ex1.getMessage());
}
```

Not working example:

```
public static class CustomNoStackException extends Exception {
    public CustomNoStackException(String msg) {
        super(msg, null, true, false);
    }
}

@Test
public void testSerializeAndDeserializeCustomNoStackException() throws Exception {
    log.info("Test: testSerializeAndDeserializeCustomNoStackException");

    CustomNoStackException ex1 = new CustomNoStackException("boom");
    ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();

    String json = om.writerFor(CustomNoStackException.class).writeValueAsString(ex1);
    assertNotNull(json);
    log.info("JSON: {}", json);

    CustomNoStackException ex2 = om.readerFor(CustomNoStackException.class).readValue(json);
    assertNotNull(ex2);
    assertEquals(ex2.getMessage(), ex1.getMessage());
}
```

In the second case, `readValue(json)` actually throws the `CustomNoStackException` wrapped in an `IOException`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an `Exception` is initialized without a `cause`, it marks itself as the `cause`.

```
private Throwable cause = this;
```

It uses that as a sentinel value to indicate that it has no cause. [`initCause`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#initCause-java.lang.Throwable-) only lets you change the `cause` if it's not itself.

Your `CustomNoStackException` constructor is initializing the `cause` with `null`, breaking the sentinel value. When Jackson later tries to call `initCause` method because of the

```
"cause":null
```

pair in the JSON, `initCause` throws an exception saying you can't overwrite an exception's `cause` (this is nested in the `JsonMappingException`).

Comment: Thank you. Would you have an idea how to fix it? Maybe override `getCause()` and annotate it `@JsonIgnore` - seems to work, but is it a good idea?